# How can I encrypt and decrypt a small text using rsa in php?

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

How can I encrypt and decrypt a small text using rsa in php without open ssl? Both private and public keys are static and in the same program.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? Else, $text = private(public($text))

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It manages the RSA and offers you several sample usages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to implement it yourself, I suggest `bcmath` for arbitrary precision calculation.

You should implement an [efficient algorithm for modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Once you've got that, you can implement the RSA operations by using that implementation.

RSA itself is easy enough...but it can encrypt numbers only, so you will have to find a numeric representation for your text. Keep in mind that the numeric representation has to be numerically smaller that the modulus, or it won't be possible to decrypt it.

My approach would be finding a block size that is small enough, splitting the clear text in blocks of that size, and encrypting those blocks with RSA. This is perfectly fine for a school assignment, but be aware that this isn't the smartest idea in a real world application.